# My karma unit tests works fine if I use Chrome in karma.conf.js but fails if changed to PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

Code segment to test:

```
$timeout(function() {

        $http.get('/getUpdates.json')
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            if (usingPopOverWait) {
              $utilUi.hidePopOverWait();
            }
            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
            if (random === 3) {
              deferred.reject('Error loading mock data');
            }
            else {
              deferred.resolve(response.data.success);
            }
          });
      }, 3000);
```

Test file:

```
    describe('Controller: CtrlHelp', function () {

      beforeEach(module('nzrbTabApp'));

      var CtrlHelp, scope, rootScope, location, timeout, httpBackend, modelHelp;

      var mockResponseHelp =
      {
        'success' : {
          'hasUpdates': true
        },
        'error': {
        }
      };

      beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

        httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        modelHelp = $injector.get('$modelHelp');
      }));

      beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $location) {

        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        location = $location;
        CtrlHelp = $controller('CtrlHelp', {
          $scope: scope,
          $location: location
        });
      }));

      it('Should load static content and attached to scope', function () {

        httpBackend.whenGET('/getUpdates.json').respond(mockResponseHelp);
        timeout.flush();
        httpBackend.flush();

        if (!scope.help.showError) {
         //check a condition
        }
      });

    });


    Error: No deferred tasks to be flushed

           at app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:121

           at app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1659

           at test/spec/features/help/ctrl-help-test.js:91
```

The error is thrown on line timeout.flush(). Same code works absolutely fine when using Chrome as browser.

Please let me know if more details are required to help on the issue above.

Regards,

Mohit

Comment: What is the timeout for? Doing the flush() on httpBackend should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sunil. I have updated my question to include more information. I have used $timeout.flush to flush all timeouts and test code inside timeout function. If I remove $timeout, I receive 'No pending request to flush' error instead. Please note error above only happens using PhantomJS instead of Chrome. Let me know please if my problem still sounds abrupt or you need any further info. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok that makes sense :) the need for the timeout.flush() was leading us astray.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `timeout` on `$http` itself? In the meantime, I'm trying to get this running to see what's going on.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia you mean something like $http.get(url,{ timeout: 3000})?? The code was written by different team member, so no idea was it wasn't implemented this way. Sorry. I am making the change and will run the tests again. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia I made the change as suggested but apparently timeout on $http behaved the same way as independent $timeout and caused same problem. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a timing issue whereby PhantomJS is hitting an empty queue, but Chrome is finding a function in it.

It's also a [known weirdness](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2507), and `ngMock.$timeout` is behaving the same way, throwing the Error on an empty queue. The workaround is to either allow for the Error, using a try-catch if necessary.

**Update**: The following code works on PhantomJS 1.9.7 on OS X (but I didn't know which defer object `deferred` was referring to.) So it sounds like the problem could be with the code under test, not the test itself.

```
var nzrbTabApp = angular.module("nzrbTabApp", []);

nzrbTabApp.controller("CtrlHelp", function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {

    $timeout(function () {

        $http.get('/getUpdates.json')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.error = "Error loading mock data";
            });
    }, 3000);
});
```

with test

```
it('Should load static content and attached to scope', function () {

    httpBackend.whenGET('/getUpdates.json').respond(mockResponseHelp);
    timeout.flush();
    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.error).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if I remove $timeout, the code segment inside timeout function is never get executed. Also the error changes to 'No pending request to flush' if I remove $timeout.flush().

Comment: @SunilD. just updated my question to include code segment under test.

Comment: Can you please compare other environment specification? Node JS 0.10.24, karma 0.10.9, PhantomJS 1.9.7 on OS X. The code segment I provided is basically what I am testing and it works fine for me on Chrome. So, I am ruling out any problems with the code as of now.

Comment: Same Kama, same PhantomJS, Node 0.10.26. This the the best I can do; the code you provided isn't testable since the controller definition is missing, including what deferred is.

Comment: Thanks Emerson. Do you think upgrading Node to 0.10.26 can make a impact? I can mail you complete js files if you would like? Thanks again for help so far.

Comment: I doubt Node has anything to do with this, but nothing wrong with being on latest stable in any case. Best way to share JS file is to put it up on plunkr or jsfiddle and paste the link here.

Comment: I have shared all the required Js files (Controller, Services, Test File) on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/mohitbansal/JP4BE/1/

Comment: I get the error on both Chrome and PhantomJS. Your test isn't acting as far as I can tell, i.e. it's assembling and asserting, but you're never actually calling `getHelpContent()` anywhere, so the defer queue remains empty. You should also try simplifying this code to narrow down the issue, there's a bit too much noise.